# Docker desktop stopped in Windows container mode

Tags: docker, windows-container

I am using Docker Desktop latest version (4.7) on Windows 10 Pro machine. Everything was working fine before my first restart after installing docker and pulling a container in `Windows Container` mode which ran successfully as well.
But now whenever I run docker, then I see `Desktop Docker stopped...` after this exception is thrown:

```
System.Exception:
Paths contain symlinks
   at Docker.Core.PermissionUtils.CheckPath(String path, Boolean allowDockerAppData) in C:\workspaces\PR-17669\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\PermissionUtils.cs:line 250
   at Docker.Core.PermissionUtils.ApplyACLOnChildren(ILogger logger, String path, Int32 recurse) in C:\workspaces\PR-17669\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\PermissionUtils.cs:line 46
   at Docker.Core.PermissionUtils.ApplyACLOnChildren(ILogger logger, String path, Int32 recurse) in C:\workspaces\PR-17669\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\PermissionUtils.cs:line 70
   at Docker.Core.PermissionUtils.ApplyACLOnChildren(ILogger logger, String path, Int32 recurse) in C:\workspaces\PR-17669\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\PermissionUtils.cs:line 70
   at Docker.Core.PermissionUtils.ApplyACLOnChildren(ILogger logger, String path, Int32 recurse) in C:\workspaces\PR-17669\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\PermissionUtils.cs:line 70
   at Docker.Core.PermissionUtils.ApplyACLOnChildren(ILogger logger, String path, Int32 recurse) in C:\workspaces\PR-17669\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\PermissionUtils.cs:line 70
   at Docker.Backend.HttpAPI.WindowsContainersController.FixPermissions(String path) in C:\workspaces\PR-17669\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\HttpAPI\WindowsContainersController.cs:line 72
   at Docker.Backend.HttpAPI.WindowsContainersController.Start(WindowsContainerStartRequest request) in C:\workspaces\PR-17669\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\HttpAPI\WindowsContainersController.cs:line 35
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass6_1.<GetExecutor>b__0(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
```

I have tried various solutions such as disabling WSL, deleting settings.json, entire docker folders in AppData, running Docker with admin rights but nothing works. Docker works fine in `Linux Container mode` but when I switch to `Windows container mode` the above exception hits and docker stops working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue - see https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/12650.
You may have to remove symlinks.